# Testing angular service subscribe/unsubscribe from within a component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-test

I have this page component class that just calls a service on load, which populates an array inside that service.  What's the best way to test the subscribe & unsubscribe functionality on this component?

```js
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy  {
    private destroySubject$: Subject<void> = new Subject();

    constructor(private accountsService: AccountsService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.accountsService.getLoginAndAccountsList$()
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroySubject$))
        .subscribe(() => { /* do nothing */ }, (error: Error) => {
            console.error('Unable to get the list of accounts!', error);
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.destroySubject$.next();
    }
}
```

My tests right now:

```js
describe('Page Component: Home', () => {
    let component: HomeComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomeComponent>;
    let debugEl: DebugElement;
    let accountsService: AccountsService;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule,],
            providers: [ AccountsService ],
            declarations: [ HomeComponent]
        }).compileComponents();
        accountsService = TestBed.get(AccountsService);
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        debugEl = fixture.debugElement;
    });

    it('should call the accountService to fetch the logins & accounts upon page load', async(() => {
        spyOn(accountsService, 'getLoginAndAccountsList$');
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(accountsService.getLoginAndAccountsList$).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));

    it('should kill the accountService subscription upon page destruction', async(() => {
        spyOn(accountsService, 'getLoginAndAccountsList$');
        fixture.detectChanges();
        component.ngOnDestroy();
        expect(????).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
...
```

The first test is working right now, but that 2nd one is not since I'm not sure what I need to be testing in there.  how can I test that the subscription is no longer active when `ngOnDestroy` is called?

Answer (score 1):

In general this is a valid question, so here is my answer:
You can test if a subscription is no longer valid, by spying on the next method of an observer. And verify that it's no longer called when the observable emits new values.

Let me elaborate:

In your component somewhere you have:

```js
obs$.pipe(
  takeUntil(destroy$$)
).subscribe(handleNewValues)
```

In the spec you should have something like this:

```js
// we need to mock the service so that we can control the values emited by the observable
let newValues = Subjects(); 
let mockService = { getLoginAndAccountsList$: () => newValues.asObservable() }

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule,],
            providers: [ {provide: AccountsService, useValue: mockService  }], // this is one way of mocking the service
            declarations: [ HomeComponent]
        }).compileComponents();

// in the test
const spy = spyOn(comp, 'handleNewValues');
comp.ngOnDestroy(); // cancels the subscription
newValues.next('test');

expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
```

In the particular use case you describe I don't see the need to use observables at all, because you're not using the values that are emitted by the observable.
Your service can have a populate function that is called in the ngOnInit